# Developing Windows Device Drivers on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, x86, windows-7-x64, device-driver

Is there a way of developing Windows Device Drivers on Linux? 
Are there any alternatives to using Visual Studio?

Comment: you'll have to reverse engineer WDK.

Answer (score 0):

Developing Windows device driver directly on Linux is not possible as we donot have a WDK linux version available[no OS based cross compiler exists].

Only way we can build is to use windows environment or else VM as specified by the other person who answered the post